# How to set the Content Disposition header with Paperclip / fog for a file hosted on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I'm using Paperclip 4.2.0 and fog 1.24.0, and host files on S3. I want to generate an expiring URL that has the "Content-Disposition" header set to "attachment".

Paperclip has [this option](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/769) to pass additional parameters to S3 expiring URLs but I can't have it working when using Paperclip with `Paperclip::Storage::Fog`.

This [fog issue](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1776) gives the following solution:

`file.url(60.seconds.from_now, { :query => { 'response-content-disposition' => 'attachment' } }`

but it does not work for me. My Rails model `ResourceDocument` has `has_attached_file :target`. `document.target.url(60.seconds.from_now, { :query => { 'response-content-disposition' => 'attachment' } }` returns the same URL than `document.target.url(60.seconds.from_now)`, ie no content-disposition is included in the generated URL: "xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/resource_documents/targets/40/2014-12-01%2017:26:20%20UTC/my_file.csv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using aws-sdk gems and it works fine for me, hope this helpful for you.

```
gem 'aws-sdk-core'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

and model's method:

```
def download_url
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  s3_videos_bucket = 'xxxx' #bucket name goes right here
  bucket = s3.buckets[s3_videos_bucket]
  object_path = 'xxxx' #file path goes right here
  object = bucket.objects[object_path]
  object.url_for(:get, { 
    expires: 60.minutes,
    response_content_disposition: 'attachment;'
  }).to_s
end
```

Comment: Thanks Xing, your solution worked for me, I just used the file path instead of the file name (`object_name = target.path`) and added the option `response_content_type: MIME::Types.of(target_file_name).first` in `url_for` else Safari was appending `.txt` to the downloaded file name.